# Whitelisting nodes in a transformer with Sanitize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, sanitize

I'm having some trouble with [this example](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) of creating a transformer lambda with the Sanitize library for Ruby.

I've gone through and thrown together a simple script that tries to Sanitize whatever's in my `options[:content]` variable, but despite hitting the bit where a hash containing an array of nodes called :node_whitelist is returned, it seems somehow my nodes aren't making the whitelist.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sanitize'

options = { :content => "<p>Here is my content. It has a video: <object width='480' height='390'><param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US'></param><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param><embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' width='480' height='390'></embed></object></p>" }

# adapted from example at https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/
video_embed_sanitizer = lambda do |env|
  node      = env[:node]
  node_name = env[:node_name]

  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up"
  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is #{node}"
  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is #{node.name.to_s.downcase}"

  # Don't continue if this node is already whitelisted or is not an element.
  if env[:is_whitelisted] then
    puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   Already whitelisted"
  end
  return nil if env[:is_whitelisted] || !node.element?

  parent = node.parent

  # Since the transformer receives the deepest nodes first, we look for a
  # <param> element or an <embed> element whose parent is an <object>.
  return nil unless (node.name.to_s.downcase == 'param' || node.name.to_s.downcase == 'embed') &&
    parent.name.to_s.downcase == 'object'

  if node.name.to_s.downcase == 'param'
    # Quick XPath search to find the <param> node that contains the video URL.
    return nil unless movie_node = parent.search('param[@name="movie"]')[0]
    url = movie_node['value']
  else
    # Since this is an <embed>, the video URL is in the "src" attribute. No
    # extra work needed.
    url = node['src']
  end

  # Verify that the video URL is actually a valid YouTube video URL.
  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   URL is #{url}"
  return nil unless url =~ /^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/v\//

  # We're now certain that this is a YouTube embed, but we still need to run
  # it through a special Sanitize step to ensure that no unwanted elements or
  # attributes that don't belong in a YouTube embed can sneak in.
  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   Node before cleaning is #{node}"
  Sanitize.clean_node!(parent, {
    :elements => %w[embed object param],

    :attributes => {
      'embed'  => %w[allowfullscreen allowscriptaccess height src type width],
      'object' => %w[height width],
      'param'  => %w[name value]
    }
  })
  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   Node after cleaning is #{node}"

  # Now that we're sure that this is a valid YouTube embed and that there are
  # no unwanted elements or attributes hidden inside it, we can tell Sanitize
  # to whitelist the current node (<param> or <embed>) and its parent
  # (<object>).
  puts "[video_embed_sanitizer]   Marking node as whitelisted and returning"
  {:node_whitelist => [node, parent]}
end

options[:content] = Sanitize.clean(options[:content], :elements => ['a', 'b', 'blockquote', 'br', 'em', 'i', 'img', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 'span', 'strong', 'ul'],
                                    :attributes => {'a' => ['href', 'title'], 'span' => ['class', 'style'], 'img' => ['src', 'alt']},
                                    :protocols => {'a' => {'href' => ['http', 'https', :relative]}},
                                    :add_attributes => { 'a' => {'rel' => 'nofollow'}},
                                    :transformers => [video_embed_sanitizer])
puts options[:content]
```

and here's the output that's being generated:

```
[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US">
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is param
[video_embed_sanitizer]   URL is http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&hl=en_US
[video_embed_sanitizer]   Node before cleaning is <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US">
[video_embed_sanitizer]   Node after cleaning is <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US">
[video_embed_sanitizer]   Marking node as whitelisted and returning
[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is param
[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is param
[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="390"></embed>
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is embed
[video_embed_sanitizer]   URL is http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&hl=en_US
[video_embed_sanitizer]   Node before cleaning is <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="390"></embed>
[video_embed_sanitizer]   Node after cleaning is <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/wjthx1GKhUI?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="390"></embed>
[video_embed_sanitizer]   Marking node as whitelisted and returning
[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is <object width="480" height="390"></object>
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is object
[video_embed_sanitizer] Starting up
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node is <p>Here is my content. It has a video: </p>
[video_embed_sanitizer]   node.name.to_s.downcase is p
<p>Here is my content. It has a video: </p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had problems with the YouTube example. Here is how I went about allowing script tags, but only for the Ooyala video player:

1. Add 'script' to :elements
2. Add 'script' => ['src'] to :attributes
3. Use :transformers => lambda { |env| next unless env[:node_name] == 'script'; unless (env[:node]['src'] && env[:node]['src'].include?('http://player.ooyala.com')); Sanitize.clean_node!(env[:node], {}); end; nil }

I also cleaned things up tremendously by creating my own initializers config as well:

```
class Sanitize
  module Config
    ULTRARELAXED = {
      :elements => [
        'a', 'b', 'blockquote', 'br', 'caption', 'cite', 'code', 'col',
        'colgroup', 'dd', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6',
        'i', 'img', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 'pre', 'q', 'small', 'strike', 'strong',
        'sub', 'sup', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'tr', 'u',
        'ul', 'object', 'embed', 'param', 'iframe', 'script'],

      :attributes => {
        'a'          => ['href', 'title'],
        'blockquote' => ['cite'],
        'col'        => ['span', 'width'],
        'colgroup'   => ['span', 'width'],
        'img'        => ['align', 'alt', 'height', 'src', 'title', 'width'],
        'ol'         => ['start', 'type'],
        'q'          => ['cite'],
        'table'      => ['summary', 'width'],
        'td'         => ['abbr', 'axis', 'colspan', 'rowspan', 'width'],
        'th'         => ['abbr', 'axis', 'colspan', 'rowspan', 'scope',
                         'width'],
        'ul'         => ['type'],
        'object' => ['width', 'height'],
        'param'  => ['name', 'value'],
        'embed'  => ['src', 'type', 'allowscriptaccess', 'allowfullscreen', 'width', 'height', 'flashvars'],
        'iframe' => ['src', 'width', 'height', 'frameborder'],
        'script' => ['src']
      },

      :protocols => {
        'a'          => {'href' => ['ftp', 'http', 'https', 'mailto', :relative]},
        'blockquote' => {'cite' => ['http', 'https', :relative]},
        'img'        => {'src'  => ['http', 'https', :relative]},
        'q'          => {'cite' => ['http', 'https', :relative]}
      },

      :transformers => lambda { |env| next unless env[:node_name] == 'script'; unless (env[:node]['src'] && env[:node]['src'].include?('http://player.ooyala.com')); Sanitize.clean_node!(env[:node], {}); end; nil }
    }
  end
end

Sanitize.clean(html, Sanitize::Config::ULTRARELAXED)
```

Comment: just fyi I could prob include a link to http://myhost.com/mystrip.js?blah=http://player.ooyala.com - maybe use a regex and include ^?

Comment: Thanks for your help modulaaron and Kevin. I've not had a chance to try this out yet, but I'll get to it soon and vote appropriately on your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Hey guys, I haven't forgotten you! I've been caught up with other things so this has had to go on the backburner for a while. I'll look into this as soon as I can. I don't want to just vote blindly without testing this out, but it does seem like modulaaron's code will do the trick (with the regexp constraint modification that Kevin mentioned to ensure the URL being tested is at the start of the string). I'll come back and vote once I've tested it. Thanks for bearing with me!

Answer (score 0):

There have been some bugs with this from time to time, make sure you're using the latest version.

Here's my working (i think) one for youtube iframe.  Disallow iframe elsewhere, then:

```
T_YOUTUBE_IFRAME = lambda do |env|
node      = env[:node]
return nil unless env[:node_name] == 'iframe'

if node['src'] =~ /^http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\//
  node['src'] += "?test" 

  return {:node_whitelist => [node]}
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin. I've not had a chance to try this out yet, but I'll get to it soon and vote appropriately on your answer as soon as I can.